Why do slam attacks sometimes do 8 digit damage?
Sometimes, when I do one of those downward smash attacks, it does 8 digits (roughly) of damage. It happens regardless of what scrolls (brutality, survival, tactics) I’ve chosen to upgrade health or stats.
The damage is also much more than any of my weapons do at the time, and sometimes is a much more reasonable number.
The damage can be so great that it’s my preferred weapon against bosses, because of the sheer amount of damage it does.
Why is this? How do I replicate it all the time? How do I increase the damage?

According to this reddit post, it's a bug that occurs on flying enemies only on 0BC. I've never had this happen before and it's the first I've heard of it; it's not clear from the post if this happens every time against flying enemies, or if it's a random thing.
The parent post includes a video of this happening, dealing 21932208 damage.
There is probably no way to increase the damage, but I don't see any reason to. Since this seems to be unintentional, there is probably no way to increase the chance of it happening, or for it to affect any non-flying enemies.

Oh yeah this happens every time I fight death. Thanks!
